# Is there a way to include Icon css code in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to add css code in UI of the shiny application. Looks like it is not taking this css code

[image]

sample code below (Note : Even single quotes does not work)

```
  tags$style(HTML(".shad {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px;
}
.icon-up:before {
    content: "\25B2";
}
.icon-down:before {
    content: "\25BC";
}")
```

Comment: `content: "\25BC";` should be `content: "\25\BC";` and `content: "\25B2";` should be `content: "\25\B2";`

Comment: NO i tried. Still the same ;9

Comment: change the double quotes to single quotes..

`content: "\25BC";` should be `content: '\25BC';`

Comment: do that for both, it should work then.

Comment: No I tried this as well. No errors. But on shiny application, Arrow does not appear

Comment: I have ````<span class='icon-up'></span>```` in my server.R

Comment: could you create this on jsfiddle so i can play with it?